# currval in sqlldr does not work for multiple rows

Tags: sql-loader

I am loading data using SQLldr into multiple tables using 1 control file. The sequence in the first table(seq.nextval) becomes input to the 2nd table(seq.currval). This does not work as the last number generated in the sequence becomes the currval for the remaining tables and it inserts that number to all the rows in the second and subsequent tables, unless I specify rows=1 to commit every row. Is there an alternative to specify commit after certain number still keeing the currval?

Control file:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '.\DATA_FILES\USERS.csv' 
APPEND 
INTO TABLE TABLE1 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY "," OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' 
trailing NULLCOLS 
( USER_ID       "SEQ_USER_ID.NEXTVAL", 
  USER_NAME,
  USER_PASSWORD "(select user_password from USERS where  
                  USER_NAME='DEMO')", 
  EXPIRY_DATE   "(select SYSDATE+1000 from dual)", 
  FAILED_ATTEMPTS CONSTANT "0"
) 
INTO TABLE TABLE2 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY "," OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' 
trailing NULLCOLS 
( USER_GROUP_ID "SEQ_USER_GROUP_ID.NEXTVAL", 
  USER_ID       "SEQ_USER_ID.CURRVAL", 
  GROUP_ID      CONSTANT "0" 
)
```

Thanks,
Anan

Comment: Please show your control file and how you are using the sequence.

Comment: LOAD DATA 
INFILE '.\DATA_FILES\USERS.csv'
APPEND
INTO TABLE TABLE1
FIELDS TERMINATED BY "," OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
trailing NULLCOLS
(
USER_ID  "SEQ_USER_ID.NEXTVAL",
USER_PASSWORD "(select user_password from USERS where USER_NAME='DEMO')",
EXPIRY_DATE "(select SYSDATE+1000 from dual)",
FAILED_ATTEMPTS  CONSTANT "0",
)
INTO TABLE TABLE2
FIELDS TERMINATED BY "," OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
trailing NULLCOLS
(
USER_GROUP_ID "SEQ_USER_GROUP_ID.NEXTVAL",
USER_ID  "SEQ_USER_ID.CURRVAL",
GROUP_ID CONSTANT "0"
)

Comment: Ok, now edit the original post to show the contents of users.csv.

Comment: I mean a sample row or 2. At least a layout.

Comment: It would just have the user_name column with values (I missed adding it as part of table 1 in the CTL file)

Comment: Please add it to the control file example then.  Be as complete as possible in your examples.  That makes it easier to help you.  We would not have to go back and forth asking for clarity if it was all spelled out from the beginning. Apply this to the job: Make sure your specs are as complete as possible before starting work.  Keeps the false starts to a minimum, gets the job done quicker with less hassle and thus cheaper with less rework.

Comment: LOAD DATA 
INFILE '.\DATA_FILES\USERS.csv'
APPEND
INTO TABLE TABLE1
FIELDS TERMINATED BY "," OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
trailing NULLCOLS
(
USER_ID  "SEQ_USER_ID.NEXTVAL",
USER_NAME,
USER_PASSWORD "(select user_password from USERS where USER_NAME='DEMO')",
EXPIRY_DATE "(select SYSDATE+1000 from dual)",
FAILED_ATTEMPTS  CONSTANT "0",
)
INTO TABLE TABLE2
FIELDS TERMINATED BY "," OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
trailing NULLCOLS
(
USER_GROUP_ID "SEQ_USER_GROUP_ID.NEXTVAL",
USER_ID  "SEQ_USER_ID.CURRVAL",
GROUP_ID CONSTANT "0"
)

Comment: I think If someone has handled such scenarios in the past the code is seldom looked at. I have added the column in the ctl code.

Comment: Edit the original post.  The comment is not the place to post file contents as there is no formatting.